# Rspec - redirect_to a path matching a regexp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I have the following in Rspec

```
response.should redirect_to %r{\A/my_settings/mysub_path/}
```

I get the following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `model_name' for Regexp:Class
```

I just need to match a part of my path which contains my_settings/mysub_path.
How is this achieved in rspec?

Answer (score 8):

To check the redirect against a regex do a string match on the response.location, like so:

```
expect(response.location).to match('your_expected_location.com')
```

Answer (score 5):

redirect_to expects a string or an active record model.

if you want to match something, you can use `response.location`

Answer (score 1):

Here's another simple way to do it:

```
response.location.should =~ /whatever_you_want_to_match/
```

Comment: I think "should" syntax is deprecated in favor of "expect".